# How do I interact with my site as a logged in user with jMeter

Tags: jmeter

I'm trying to load test my web server with jMeter, I'm able to successfully log in using the POST request to the login page, but other pages are being redirected as if my threads are not authenticated.

http://puu.sh/6MCu3.png

Anything after the HTTP request 'Login (POST)' is redirected to the homepage. It's kind of ruining my testing. I have a Cookie Manager added as well:

http://puu.sh/6MCwP.png

Do I need to add custom cookies? Are pages visited in order of the User Group tree?

Comment: Can you share the URL of the site you are trying to login to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes, pages ARE visited in the order of the tree.
2. Without knowing the specifics of your app I'm guessing there is some dynamic authentication token which needs to be extracted from your initial request and then passed into future requests.

Here are a couple of videos which explain how to do logins with JMeter:
http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/80479-how-to-use-jmeter-for-login-authentication

Answer (score 1):

Your Cookie Manager looks good. Perhaps you might be missing something like "VIEWSTATE" which is popular method of page state management mechanism widely used in Java and .NET Web Applications.

Record your test case flow with [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP%28S%29_Test_Script_Recorder) or [Google Chrome plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/blazemeter-the-load-testi/mbopgmdnpcbohhpnfglgohlbhfongabi?hl=en) which is easier and mention what parameters are being sent along with the requests. If you'll see something like `VIEWSTATE` you'll need to add some correlation to your tests to get this viewstate value from page source and add it to further requests.

It'll be something like

```
<input id="viewState" type="hidden" value="/wEPDwUBMGRkMSHDB101+52k3J/FmXSyR78uK/g=" name="viewState">
```

You need to extract this value `/wEPDwUBMGRkMSHDB101+52k3J/FmXSyR78uK/g=` and pass it as a parameter.

The best way to obtain it is using [XPath Extractor](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0)

Relevant XPath expression will look like:

```
//input[@id='viewState']/@value
```

Another technique is using [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) Post Processor but regular expressions are more complex to develop, especially multiline ones, and they're vulnerable to even minor markup changes.

Another showstopper may be [CSRF filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) - a security technique which validates origin of the request. In this case you'll need to construct a relevant HTTP Header or HTTP Request parameter holding this value.

You can use [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) to send CSRF header and possible `User-Agent` string to pretend more like a real browser.

Hope this helps